# When comparing two identical strings they return as different

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

I have the first password from a text box:

```
pwtextbox = TextBox2.Text
```

and the other one I am reading from a DB Table:

```
pwdatabase = SQLdr("pw")
```

I've tried to compare them using '=', StrComp, and `strings.compare` and they always, no matter what, come as different

```
While SQLdr.Read() 'While Data is Present
        pwdatabase = SQLdr("pw") 'pwdatabase is equal db entry
        Response.Write(pwtextbox & "=" & pwdatabase & "?<br>") 'is mickey=mickey?
        If StrComp(pwtextbox, pwdatabase) = 0 Then 
            Response.Write("login successful")
            Response.Write(pwdatabase & "is the pass")
        Else
            Response.Write("wrong password.  ")
            Response.Write(TextBox2.Text & " is the wrong pass. the right password is " & pwdatabase)

        End If
    End While
```

the onscreen display outputs as follow:

mickey=mickey?
wrong password.
mickey is the wrong password. the right password is mickey.

I can't seem to understand!
especially when I see on the screen that the two strings are identical, I still get this false positive...

can you see what I'm missing?

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing passwords in plain text? :(

Comment: Is `pwdatabase` returning an object from `SQLdr("pw")`?

Comment: Did you check for spaces?

Comment: Please add the code where you declare `pwtextbox` and `pwdatabase`. What is the datatype in the datapabe of the "pw" field? Also, compare the lengths to make sure they are the same. `pwtextbox.length = pwdatabase.Length`